# Why is this shadow DOM height only 100% with two heights?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom

I ran into this by accident while trying to get my shadow DOM element to be 100%.

Here's an example:

https://jsbin.com/ceqajareci/1/edit?html,css,js,output

But, specifically:

```
  // the -5px offsets the shadow
  height: calc(100vh - 5px);
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
```

If I remove either one of those the height is no longer 100%. It seems to only work if I have two heights.

The goal though is to have a 100% shadow DOM element. This element is going inside a resizable (to the end user) tool. So the user can add a button and resize it so I want the height to be the entire container. So, technically this works but I have no idea why and I'd like it to have 1 height

Example if I take one of the two out:

[image]

Here you'll see I removed what should be overridden

[image]

Comment: You can keep only the last one and I am sure it will work because only the last one will be considered

Comment: @TemaniAfif I posted an example. What you said is what the question is about :) I dont understand why removing the 100vh makes the 100% height work.

Comment: can you create a snippet here? the screenshots your are showing are differet from what we get in your link

Comment: @TemaniAfif is right and what you see is a bug (at 1st display)  in Jsbin. Moreover you don't use Shadow DOM